# Is there any way to limit the scope of a knockout.js application?

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js

I have a legacy project which I have been approved to work in a `knockout.js` module.  This is great however the application is extremely complex and I need to use some of the pre-built form validation of our application.  My form validators work fine until a dynamic template gets switched out.  I can't for the life of me figure out the error.  Nothing in the console and my vast debugging efforts have been fruitless.  I'm thinking that my solution could be something along the lines of limiting the scope of the knockout application similar to how one can declare `ng-app` in `angular.js`.  I can't find a working example of how to do this or any documentation relevant to `knockout.js`

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.  Thank you ladies and gentlemen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ko.applyBindings takes an optional second parameter which is an element to treat as the root.

e.g.

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#app")[0])
```